# Crystal Reports: Keeping details sections as a whole

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm having a little layout problem here.
I'm developing a few Crystal reports, some of them tend to get pretty extensive concerning tables and such so they are divided into subreports. These subreports then get loaded onto the main report with a titel firld above it.

The issue I'm currently having is keeping the subreport and the subreport together. Often, te title of the details section is placed at the bottom of 1 page and the subreport on the next page. This isn't very nice-looking....

Answer (score 1):

Yup, it's pretty simple:

1. In Section Expert, select the Detail section.
2. If there are multiple detail sections, you must select the outermost Detail section which contains the others.
3. Select **Keep Together**.